# Curve fitting using Scipy

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to find the optimum values of 7 parameters (a, b, c, d, e, f, g). But the following code is giving me a ValueError (saying that operands could not be broadcast together). I cannot figure out what the problem is (I am certain, the urinary_excretion function works).

The data file I used is [here](http://www.filedropper.com/data1_4).

```
"""
read the matrix values from excel spreadsheet, and converts the values to a matrix, shape = (28, 28)
"""

RMatrix=(pd.read_excel("C:\\...Data.xlsx", sheetname='TestModel', skiprows=0)).as_matrix()

"""
read the initialAmount values from excel spreadsheet, and converts the values to a matrix, shape = (28, 1)
"""

initialAmount = (pd.read_excel("C:\\...Data.xlsx", sheetname="TMI", skiprows=0)).as_matrix() 
xdata = [4, 46, 67, 106, 158, 162, 201, 220, 249, 277, 309, 336, 371, 4453, 550, 687, 704, 737, 760, 795, 823]
ydata = [0.0054, 0.003, 0.00079,  0.00106,  0.00091759999999999997, 0.00014, 0.0006845, 0.0004995, 0.000865, 0.00083, 8.325e-05, 0.000149,  0.002738, 0.0007, 0.00059,  0.000185,  0.00048,  0.000369,  0.000925,  0.0015169, 0.000185]

def urinary_excretion(x, a, b, c, d, e, f, g):

    initialAmount[0,0] = a #Replace the 0,0th element of initialMatrix with 'a' 
    initialAmount[1,0] = b # Replace the 1,0th element of initialMatrix with 'b'
    initialAmount[2,0] = c #and so on

    RMatrix[0,2] = d #Replace the 0,2th element of RMatrix with 'd'
    RMatrix[0,1] = e # and so on
    RMatrix[1,0] = f
    RMatrix[1,2] = g

    RMatrix[np.isnan(RMatrix)]=0 #converts NaN (Not a number) to 0
    row,col = np.diag_indices_from(RMatrix) #get row and column indices of diagonal elements
    RMatrix[row,col] = -(RMatrix.sum(axis=1)-RMatrix[row,col])-Lambda #assign the sum of each row except the diagonal elements into diagonal positions, takes care of decay constant
    AMatrix = RMatrix.T # Transpose the RMatrix

    def content(t):
        expMatrix = scipy.linalg.expm(t*AMatrix)
        return numpy.dot(expMatrix, initialAmount)

    return content(x).item(20) - content(x-1).item(20)

popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(urinary_excretion, xdata, ydata)
```

Comment: Try getting rid of numpy.matrix and replace it with numpy.array

Comment: Still does not fix the problem. :(

Comment: please trim it down to a minimum self-contained reproducible example. E.g. embed the data from that `pandas.read_excel` etc.

Comment: You're probably better off giving explicit initial values  `curve_fit(...., p0=init_values)`.  It appears you're taking `.item(20)` of an ndarray to generate the return value:  that would be a scalar value, I think.  `curve_fit` requires more observations returned than variable sent in (in your case, 7).

Comment: @ev-br, The RMatrix is a 28 x 28 matrix, and the initialAmoung matrix is 28 x 1 Matrix. I thought it would be less cumbersome to just post the link to the excel file, instead of pasting the whole matrix here.

Comment: @DPdl making a smaller example is a part of making an MCVE (and not accidentally, that's a viable debugging tool)